nextcloud container has no access to datase
I use nextcloud with mariadb in docker container under Portainer. I just updated both, but now the Nextcloud container has no more access to the database. Wether over the IP nor over the alias.

Failed to connect to the database: An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Host is unreachable

what make me nuts is, I can access the Database in the same network over an phpmyadmin Container. So the local IP is correct. But I can't ping from the nextcloud to the mariadb Container.
Since I use Portainer I thought everything is easy and the Network with the name "nextcloud_default" is shown at all three Container I use. But what can do if this failed?

I digging deeper the problem is indeed the connection - so here are the details of the network.
(a) container which needs access
                   docker inspect  nextcloud

        ...
"Networks": {
            "nextcloud_default": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": [
                    "nextcloud",
                    "9e4f1ba76095",
                    "161b41cf5098"
                ],
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:02",
                "DriverOpts": null,
                "NetworkID": "2d07ea858843636bd00097ebdde760b04fa79e989c0dd4062672fc14cc100c15",
                "EndpointID": "6ff192958e3984c657549ca5d151179ac6986f40f65fce4524b305f3c28d6d98",
                "Gateway": "172.23.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.23.0.3",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "DNSNames": [
                    "nextcloud",
                    "9e4f1ba76095",
                    "161b41cf5098",
                    "a915227c31af"
                ]
            }
        }

(b) Container with the Mariadb
               docker inspect  nextcloud_db

"Networks": {
                "nextcloud_default": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "nextcloud_db",
                        "nextcloud_db",
                        "d356cfb24b2d"
                    ],
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null,
                    "NetworkID": "2d07ea858843636bd00097ebdde760b04fa79e989c0dd4062672fc14cc100c15",
                    "EndpointID": "8412b1d3a93a96549425f97f487b7b0cb0c1d6b4f6ba46f5b4a62176a16507c5",
                    "Gateway": "172.23.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.23.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "DNSNames": [
                        "nextcloud_db",
                        "d356cfb24b2d"
                    ]
                }

What make me curios are the aliases in the "nextcloud" Container only the "94f.." exist and make sense.
The network look like this.
    docker network inspect nextcloud_default
...
            "Containers": {
            "a915227c31af4e489a4dce8b17228eb75cc1f4c52726609e07aa14e0f952c041": {
                "Name": "nextcloud",
                "EndpointID": "6ff192958e3984c657549ca5d151179ac6986f40f65fce4524b305f3c28d6d98",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "bde60fc81bcd956e71a4dfa60cf86ec40ced3ad19d1968d7fb832f56cdb71d0f": {
                "Name": "Phpmyadmin",
                "EndpointID": "315857ac9ca4fba3f99d5bcf7c1d6e7f4892cce6917083084222bd7d7c83c801",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "d356cfb24b2d03af6efe4cc803267b02af05f1e1f957ea2328d380d814845eb0": {
                "Name": "nextcloud_db",
                "EndpointID": "8412b1d3a93a96549425f97f487b7b0cb0c1d6b4f6ba46f5b4a62176a16507c5",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },

I just try it with a small PHP Code in the nextcloud container (with the working access data from phpmyadmin)
    try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  echo "Connected successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
  echo "\n";
}

The answer is: Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Host is unreachable
